# How to strictly check my html, css and js sources againts specifications?

Tags: javascript, html, css, validation, browser

Modern browsers supress many errors in html, css and js sources. Is there a way to see  what exactly is wrong with my sources? I want to see all mistakes, even the smallest ones.

Comment: Use https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: When you say mistakes do you knwo what to expect, or trying to look into?

Comment: One of the best ways to detect coding errors is to use a lint extension in your IDE. Which editor do you use to write your code (e.g. VS Code)?

Comment: Open the console in the DevTools, then activate Errors, Warnings, Logs, Info and CSS outputs to see what is going on under the hood.

Comment: @Teemu how can I activate CSS output in the console? Is it available in Google Chrome? If not, what browser then?

Comment: @JohnLaw Firefox console has all the features I've listed above.

Answer (score 1):

you could you ESLint, stylelint and html-validator npm packages for that